# How find this polynomial such $(f,f'(x))=h(x)$,but $f(x)$ the geometric and algebraic multiplicities is one

Tags: polynomials

Let $h(x)$ be a polynomial of non-zero degree over a field $F$.

I am wondering whether there must always exist a [Frobenius Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_polynomial) $f \in F[x]$ satisfying the following:

1. $\operatorname{deg}(f)>0$
2. The geometric and algebraic multiplicities of each root of $f$ is $1$.
3. The  greatest common divisor $\gcd(f,f')=h(x)$.

Thank you for  you help

Comment: Could you add more text to explain what you mean? Or could you add a translation to your native language, if that is not English? Also, is $f'$ the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Yes,$f'$ is derivative of $f$,and I have edit.Thank you

Comment: Yes,Thank you,That's my mean

Comment: One more question: you write this out starting with $f$, but it looks like actually you're trying to start with $h$, and find out if $f$ exists. Or did you mean to assume that $h$ is Frobenius, instead of assuming that $f$ is?

Comment: I rewrote the question. Please check if I did it right. If I made it all wrong, you can go to the edit history and revert.